# How to resolve this NoSuchMethodError in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have this code which is supposed to return the userId. Problem is it returns null since the user is signed out.

```
@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
try {
  widget.auth.currentUser().then((userId) {
    setState(() {
     authStatus = userId == null ? AuthStatus.notSignedIn : AuthStatus.signedIn;
    });
  });
} catch (e) {}
}
```

This still throws an error even after wrapping a catch block around it. the error freezes my app
Error:

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid
```

The method trying to be called is

```
Future<String> currentUser() async {
FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
return user.uid;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
     widget.auth.currentUser().then((userId) {
        setState(() {
         authStatus = userId == null ? AuthStatus.notSignedIn : AuthStatus.signedIn;
        });
      }).catchError((onError){
        authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;
      });
```

**Update**
If the firebaseAuth return null you can't use uid property from user because it's null.

```
    Future<String> currentUser() async {
      FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
      return user != null ? user.uid : null;
    }
```

Comment: It is in the first code snippet i.e  `widget.auth.currentUser().then((userId)`  auth is an instance of another class which has the firebase authorization logic. `currentUser` is a method in the class . Hope my answer makes sense

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I am encountering the same problem here

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you're watching the login playlist of Andrea Bizzotto, am I right?

I've passed through it too. The way I managed so that I could fix the error was change the position of `auth.currentUser()` declaration. You probably have created your `Auth auth` inside the `StatelessWidget`.

Try to move the instance of `Auth` from `StatelessWidget` to your `State`, right before your `void initState()`.

And also replace your code so that you can access your `Auth` from the `State`. Like this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    try {
      auth.currentUser().then((userId) { //I've removed the 'widget.'
        setState(() {
          authStatus =
              userId == null ? AuthStatus.notSignedIn : AuthStatus.signedIn;
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

Once you did this, your code should not throw this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseUser _user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_user == null) {
      return AuthStatus.notSignedIn;
    } else {
      return AuthStatus.signedIn;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _checkUser() async {
    _user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    setState(() {});
  }
```