# I'm getting an error NoSuchMethodError: The method currentUser was called on null.FLUTTER

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to check whether the user is signed in or not, I've authenticated  my flutter app with firebase, I want the status of the user to redirect the app to either login page or home page, but I can't run the app it shows the error on red screen and the error is:
    NoSuchMethodError: The method 'currentUser' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: currentUser()

I saw the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952622/10787445)
but I did not understood it properly

currentUser function:

```
Future<String> currentUser() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  return user!= null ? user.uid : null;
}
```

checking the authentication status:

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
  try {
    widget.auth.currentUser().then((userId) {
    setState(() {
    authStatus =
    userId == null ? AuthStatus.notsignedIn : AuthStatus.signedIn;
   });
  });
} catch (e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error just means that your `_firebaseAuth` object is null. Try using

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
```